Local coordinates for a quadratic form
Suppose we have a real quadratic form in $v = (x_1, \, x_2, \, \cdots, \, x_n)$, which we WLOG can assume after an orthogonal change of coordinates to be
$$q(v) = -\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 + \sum_{i =k+1}^n x_i^2 = 1.$$
If $1 \leq k \leq n$, the form has $k$ positive eigenvalues and $n-k$ negative eigenvalues, leading to a hyperboloid of composed of sheets, depending on $k$.
We want to find local (paraboloid) coordinates for the $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal M = \{v : q(v)=1\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. We want to impose either polar or hyperbolic coordinates for each dimension, depending on the sign of eigenvalues of the metric ("timelike" coordinates vs. "spacelike" coordinates): in this case the metric is a diagnonal matrix $g$ with
$$g_{ii} = \begin{cases} -1 &\text{ for }  1 \leq i \leq k \\ 1 &\text{ for } n-k \leq i \leq n \end{cases}.$$
I am struggling to find the the exact parametrization (local coordinates) from $u$ to $x$,
$$\begin{cases}
x_1 = f_1(u_1, \, u_2, \cdots, u_{n-1}), \\
x_2 = f_2(u_1, \, u_2, \cdots, u_{n-1}), \\
\vdots \\
x_n = f_n(u_1, \, u_2, \cdots, u_{n-1})
\end{cases}.$$
Thanks.

Hint : consider parametrizations based on hyperbolic functions $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ like for Minkowski space here (formula (1.5)).

@JeanMarie Thanks for the typo catch!
